# Efficiency question with excel using index match for each cell in a large sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 4 types of customers, each pay in a different payment plan.
group 1 - monthly
group 2 - semi monthly
group 3 - bi weekly
group 4 - weekly

I have a sheet with a range of all the relevant payment dates for those group sorted in the right order in row 1

I would like that for each customer there will be a data validation list (group 1,group 2, group 3,group 4)

When selected the customer's row will populate on the correct dates according to his group number and the date the payment starts.

My work around to do that was to create 4 separate sheets for each group, auto populate from the correct date and run it for all customers in each group meaning you can see for John Doe what and when will be his payments in each group even though he is in group 3 for example. And a MAIN sheet where John Doe has group 3 selected where a MATCH and INDEX is running to find when he is supposed to pay and how much. The issue is that for 400 rows and 300 column this becomes heavy.

How would you go about solving that?

each cell looks like this in the MAIN sheet

```
=LET(mothlydate,Monthlyrd3!$BK$3:AAC$3,semidate,Monthlyth16!$BK$3:ZZ$3,namemonthly,Monthlyrd3!$BK79:AAC79,namesemi,Monthlyth16!$BK79:ZZ79,

IF(OR($BA96="Monthly 3 rd",$BA96="Semi-Monthly",$BA96="Monthly 16 th"),
IF((IF(IFERROR(INDEX(namemonthly,1,MATCH(GH$2,mothlydate,0)),"")+IFERROR(INDEX(namesemi,1,MATCH(GH$2,semidate,0)),"")>$AE96,$AE96,IFERROR(INDEX(namemonthly,1,MATCH(GH$2,mothlydate,0)),"")+IFERROR(INDEX(namesemi,1,MATCH(GH$2,semidate,0)),"")))=0,"",(IF(IFERROR(INDEX(namemonthly,1,MATCH(GH$2,mothlydate,0)),"")+IFERROR(INDEX(namesemi,1,MATCH(GH$2,semidate,0)),"")>$AE96,$AE96,IFERROR(INDEX(namemonthly,1,MATCH(GH$2,mothlydate,0)),"")+IFERROR(INDEX(namesemi,1,MATCH(GH$2,semidate,0)),"")))),

IF($BA96="Bi-Weekly 1",(IFERROR(INDEX(NewBiWeekly!$BK79:AAC79,1,MATCH(GH$2,NewBiWeekly!$BK$3:AAC$3,0)),"")),IF($BA96="Bi-Weekly 2",(IFERROR(INDEX(NewBiWeeklyTwo!$BK79:AAC79,1,MATCH(GH$2,NewBiWeeklyTwo!$BK$3:AAC$3,0)),"")),IF($BA96="Other",(IFERROR(INDEX(NewOther!$BK79:AAC79,1,MATCH(GH$2,NewOther!$BK$3:AAC$3,0)),""))))))
)
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: Please share some sample data, so it's easier for us to test.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a purely textual analysis of your formula, since data required for a meaningful analysis hasn't been forthcoming:
the expression below occurs 4 times in your formula

```
IFERROR(INDEX(namesemi,1,MATCH(GH$2,semidate,0)),"")
```

as does this one

```
IFERROR(INDEX(namemonthly,1,MATCH(GH$2,mothlydate,0))
```

which means that, in the worst-case circumstances, one or both expressions are being evaluated on FOUR separate occasions - it would be sensible to consider making one or both of these named 'values' at the start of the LET() function, such that, in the worst-case cirumstances going forward, each would be evaluated only once.